# Search Using LIKE and OR

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
if(!isset($_GET['query'])) {
  echo "<h1>No search query specified.</h1><a href='index.php'>Return</a>";
} else {
  $query = trim($_GET['query']);
  $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM warps 
                        WHERE name LIKE '%$query%' 
                        OR desc LIKE '%$query%' OR keywords LIKE '%$query'");
  if($query) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       echo $row['name'];
    }
  } else {
    echo "<h1>No results found</h1>";
  }
}
```

Why is it not returning any results when I enter a search query which corresponds to information in my database?

Comment: Does `$_GET['query']` array is not empty.

Comment: Are you going to tell us how you fixed it Joshwaa?

Comment: By putting backticks around the column names. Desc is a reserved mysql keyword, completely forgot.

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, please write it in an answer and accept.

Answer (score 3):

You must not call a field desc. Or if you call it like that use it like this `desc`. DESC is a command so in your query MySQL thinks you want something to be decreasing.

Comment: +1. The list of reserved keywords: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to "var_dump" your query and the result, you get back.
Make sure you have error reporting enabled:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Your query as already mentioned, contains the MySQL-Keyword DESC as column name.
If there is no way to rename that column, you may enclose it in backticks like this:

```
`desc`
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, you have opted not to delimit your field names with backticks.

You can often get away with this, but in your case you cannot because `DESC` is a keyword.

Write:

```
SELECT * FROM `warps`
 WHERE `name` LIKE '%$query%' 
    OR `desc` LIKE '%$query%'
    OR `keywords` LIKE '%$query'
```